# ConnectionString not found have tried multiple ways

Tags: c#, mysql, configuration, connection-string

Connection string not found i have tried multiple ways but all goes in vein, i have a data access layer project in `app.config` i have mention connection string

```
 </configuration>
     <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MySqlConnectionString" connectionString="server=myserver;User Id=myuser;password=mypassword;database=mydatabase"
     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```

C# Code

```
public void ConnectionString()
{
    try
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString; //does not work
        var connectionString2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySqlConnectionString"];//does not work
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

What am doing wrong i have try multiple solution it does not work for me

[ConnectionString Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ4Sd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your **connection string name** is `Default`. And you should consider this detail when you want to read it. Try like this;

```
public void ConnectionString()
        {
            try
            {
                 var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString;

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Or you can change **connection string name** as you wish;

```
</configuration>
     <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MySqlConnectionString" connectionString="server=myserver;User Id=myuser;password=mypassword;database=mydatabase"
     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: sorry wrong picture has attached with the question both keys are same and not working

Comment: It should work. You should define connection strings inside app.config of your execution project, not inside app.config of "data access layer" project.

Comment: i have two project one is dal and other is a web solution  i have added the connection string in both project.

Comment: Web.config of the web project and app.config in class library project not working. both have connectionstrings setting

Comment: Remove second line. "var connectionString2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySqlConnectionString"];//does not work"

Answer (score 0):

From the picture I can see an "app.config" and a "web.config", so I presume there are different projects. Am I right? If it is, you have to add the connectionString on the execution project (if it is a web site, or a standalone, or whatever it is).

The code you were using is correct

```
  var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

It has to work correctly.

Comment: Yes different project one is class library project and other is asp.net mvc application. Class library has app.config and web project has web.config file database connection and query is managed in the dal project i don't know what's going wrong

Comment: the key is: "**you have to add the connectionString on the execution project**" as Fenuska said

Comment: @JohnDoe add the connectionString on the web config of the MVC application, and let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Every one for helping my the main issue was i have added connectionstring attribute in the wrong place

Wrong place

```
 <runtime>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MySqlConnectionString" connectionString="server=myserver;User Id=myuser;password=mypassword;database=mydatabse"
   providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Right place i have cut the connection string under the runtime attribute and paste it alone and the issue is solved

```
<connectionStrings>
          <add name="MySqlConnectionString" connectionString="server=myserver;User Id=myuser;password=mypassword;database=mydatabse"
       providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
        </connectionStrings>
```

Thanks everyone